# Gensim unable to load word2vec models

Tags: python, gensim

I trained a word2vec model using gensim on my local machine and uploaded all files to AWS. I am able to load the model on my local machine but loading on AWS gives

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 's3://saltsagemaker/models/bilstm_models/word2vec/word2vec_model.wv.vectors.npy'

This works

```
# LOCAL MACHINE
from gensim.models import Phrases, Word2Vec
WV_MODEL = 'model_train_script/models/bilstm_models/word2vec/word2vec_model'
wv_model = Word2Vec.load(WV_MODEL)
```

This doesnt works

```
# AWS CODE
from gensim.models import Phrases, Word2Vec
WV_MODEL = 's3://saltsagemaker/models/bilstm_models/word2vec/word2vec_model'
wv_model = Word2Vec.load(WV_MODEL)
```

above code gives the following

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> 's3://saltsagemaker/models/bilstm_models/word2vec/word2vec_model.wv.vectors.npy'

Files uploaded on local machine
[image]

Files uploaded on AWS
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `numpy` code on which Gensim relies to load subsidiary files (like your `word2vec_model.wv.vectors.npy`) doesn't support remote S3 paths like `'s3://saltsagemaker/models/bilstm_models/word2vec/word2vec_model.wv.vectors.npy'`. So, it's interpreting it as if it were a local path – & finding nothing.

You could:

- download the files manually, to a local temporary space, before use; or
- avoid using the Gensim object's custom `.save()` & `.load()` methods at all, & instead use Python's `pickle` functionality to write the model object to a single file, then use `unpickle` on that single file to read it back in from a single S3 path

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Windows drive, so it was already local in my case. The "solution" for me was to do

```
import os    
os.chdir('my_funky_drive_name://file_location')
```

so in your case that would be

```
import os    
from gensim.models import Phrases, Word2Vec

os.chdir('s3://saltsagemaker')

WV_MODEL = './models/bilstm_models/word2vec/word2vec_model'
wv_model = Word2Vec.load(WV_MODEL)
```

Hopefully this will be resolved in Numpy.